# Uncertainty of earthquake location

Tags: estimation, uncertainty

Maximum of the so-called image function in the figure below interpreted as earthquake location (in XY plane in this case). The shape of this function will depend (upon other things) on frequency of the signal, amount of noise in the data. I need to quantify uncertainty of location using this function. One of the approaches I found in the literature is based on assumption that this function below represents behavior similar to likelihood function. Then this function can be converted to PDF assuming distribution close to normal.

In the literature mentioned above, this function is made up by adding signal amplitudes at different stations (stacking across array of seismic stations). Function in the figure below are semblance values over a grid of points in XY plane. Semblance is defined as: squared sum divided by sum of squares of signal amplitude (see page 2 eq 3 here http://www.ahay.org/RSF/book/tccs/avo/paper.pdf)

How to check if this way of constructing the PDF correct? Is there another approach to estimate uncertainty in location from the image function below?

[image]

Comment: "Validity" in what sense? How exactly is it calculated?

Comment: By validity I meant, how to check if this way of constructing pdf is correct. I have edited the question to show how this image function was calculated.